# Wait between trips

Tags: international-travel, us-citizens

I am to travel to Malaysia for vacation when I get back to the US I will only be here about a 3 weeks before I go on a cruise.  Will there be any issue or wait time required between these trips?

I am a US citizen.

Comment: Any issue with who?

Comment: Are you a US citizen?  If not, what is your citizenship, visa type, and immigration status?

Comment: Your friends might be jealous but otherwise there is no reason to have a problem. You can travel as often as you like.

Comment: I was asking because of the woman that had traveled and brought back a virus that had infected people here. Yes I am a US citizen

Comment: What virus? From where, Malaysia? How is it relevant to a cruise, are you thinking about some kind of quarantine?

Comment: I do not recall from where and it was an airborne pathogen that was transferred to all she had come in contact with in several states. This was a few years ago. I just want to make sure that one trip will not effect the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can travel as often as you like. Going to Malaysia for vacation does not have any impact on your ability to take a cruise later. Enjoy your vacation and your cruise.

If you show symptoms of a serious infectious disease, you may be advised by doctors not to travel in order to protect the public, and in rare and serious cases, could be quarantined by public health officials. If this happens to you, I assure you that you'll know about it. Occasionally, there are special travel bans for people who have possible exposure to extremely contagious diseases. Such situations are extremely rare, widely publicized, and generally involve cases such as health care workers who have been treating Ebola patients.

Here is [the CDC's advice for travel health for Malaysia](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/malaysia).

---

For immigration purposes, repeated and lengthy trips to the same country could pose a problem, depending on your immigration status and that country's rules. It doesn't sound like that's your concern in this question though, but it's worth noting.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, and I realize I just wrote an answer, I still don't exactly understand your question, but I'm glad I helped...I think?

Comment: Well Zach,  I was told that I might not be able to go on the cruise if I had recently been out of the country.  So I was just trying to find out how true that might be.  I was given the reference of that woman a few years that traveled abroad and came back with a virus and infected others.  I'm sure my friend ment well in telling me to check.

Comment: @GIGISMITH Some (all?) cruise lines may have you fill out [a little form](https://help.carnival.com/ci/fattach/get/220034/1467307848/redirect/1/filename/Pre-Boarding%20Public%20Health%20Questionnaire%20-%20USA%20-%2006-10-16.pdf) when you board asking if you have diarrhea, vomiting, fever, flulike symptoms, or are pregnant. If so, they're going to want to talk to you and would deny boarding if they think you could make others sick. That's the same whether you've traveled recently or not though. Have a great trip!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge and thank you for the well wishes. You have been very helpful.